# Communication between QThread and boost threads

Tags: c++, boost-thread, qthread

The Gui is in `Qt` and Api is in `boost`. The Gui is meant to sit on top of Api. One of the functions of Api is to do network level data management, process data in certain ways and communicate with the Gui (ie., bridge Gui with other end of Api). To keep the GUI from freezing Api does it's work in a separate thread. If both Gui and Api had used Qt, communication would have been easier with cross-threaded `signal-slot` mechanism of Qt. Api `emits` and returns immediately and vice-versa. So none would be blocked unless explicitly specified (`Qt::BlockingQueuedConnection`). I've been using `boost` only since a while back as it was required to code new Api in `boost`. How do i achieve this mechanism in `boost <--> Qt` communication? Api is going to be header+static_library and so Gui and Api will produce single executable. I have to support Linux, Windows and Mac minimum.

**Edit:**: Sorry, but already had a long winded discussion (to put it mildly) with the management, but the net outcome is i "have" to use boost in Api. Infact the Gui might not even use Qt. Anybody with a Gui should be able to plug into our Api for communication with the other end (sort of a Gui--API--kernel model). So suggestions about using Qt on either side etc., is not going to be of much help

Comment: Faced similar problem. I switched to Qt on both sides.

Comment: can say the same as @amankamboj1 - QT threads are sufficient and its a baaaad idea to mix 'em up - or better, its just not worth the hassle